# what about last line of xml what should be the corresponding dtd for that

Tags: xml, dtd

**XML file**

root name college.it has two child nodes principal and teacher.i wrote a corresponding dtd for that but what about a single a text line with no element attach to it.how to write a corresponding dtd line for that.the line is:

```
 This college is ranked 7th in the university
```

Answer (score 0):

If an element can contain text content (other than whitespace) it must use the Mixed content model. eg.:

```
<!ELEMENT college (#PCDATA | principal | teacher)*>
```

The Mixed content model doesn't allow you to add any further restrictions. For example you can't require that `principal` is used only once or comes before `teacher`.

Normally Mixed content is used for document-like semi-structured data. Might it be better to kick that extra information into a `<ranking>` element?

Comment: so you are trying to say that for last line i.e the text one which has no tag element associated with it. i should write  <!ELEMENT college (#PCDATA | principal | teacher)*> and it will take care of "This college is ranked 7th in the university"
?

Comment: If that's the data you've got and it needs to validate, yes, that's the `<!ELEMENT>` declaration you'd have to put in your DTD.